# Как гарантированно выбрать из регулярки отдельную часть строки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
/(Boeing\s?)?7[1-8]7(-[0-9](00)?(\/[0-9]00)?)?i?((L|E)R)?(\s|with)?(\(?winglets\)?)?/g
```

Которое предназначено для матчей со следующими строками, в которых есть нечто общее, что встречается в каждой строке - поколение самолёта (737, 757, 777, 787 и так далее) :

```
787
Boeing 737
Boeing 757-200
Boeing 737-800 (winglets)
Boeing 777-300ER
Boeing 787-8
Boeing737-800(winglets)
Boeing737-800withwinglets
Boeing777-200/300
Boeing 747-8i
Boeing777-200/200ER
```

Как можно вытащить это значение используя данное регулярное выражение?

Comment: Какое значение?

Comment: @Эникейщик код поколения самолёта. 737, 767, 787.

Comment: А зачем тут регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

match ведь возвращает массив совпадений. 

Вот и можно дотать оттуда всё необходимое через `.map`

```js
let str = `
  787
  Boeing 737
  Boeing 757-200
  Boeing 737-800 (winglets)
  Boeing 777-300ER
  Boeing 787-8
  Boeing737-800(winglets)
  Boeing737-800withwinglets
  Boeing777-200/300
  Boeing 747-8i
  Boeing777-200/200ER
`

console.log( 
  str.match(/(Boeing\s?)?(7[1-8]7)(-[0-9](00)?(\/[0-9]00)?)?i?((L|E)R)?(\s|with)?(\(?winglets\)?)?/g)
     .map( e => e.match(/(Boeing\s?)?(7[1-8]7)/)[2] )
  
);
```

Есть еще метод `matchAll`, плохо поддерживается.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы просто хотите модифицировать ваше регулярное выражение, добавьте захватывающую подмаску вокруг `7[1-8]7` (`(7[1-8]7)`):

```
/(Boeing\s?)?(7[1-8]7)(-[0-9](00)?(\/[0-9]00)?)?i?((L|E)R)?(\s|with)?(\(?winglets\)?)?/
```

```js
var strs = ['787','Boeing 737','Boeing 757-200','Boeing 737-800 (winglets)','Boeing 777-300ER','Boeing 787-8','Boeing737-800(winglets)','Boeing737-800withwinglets','Boeing777-200/300','Boeing 747-8i','Boeing777-200/200ER'];
var rx = /(Boeing\s?)?(7[1-8]7)(-[0-9](00)?(\/[0-9]00)?)?i?((L|E)R)?(\s|with)?(\(?winglets\)?)?/;
for (var i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  var m = strs[i].match(rx);
  if (m) { 
    console.log(strs[i], "=>", m[2]);
  }
}
```

Однако всё можно сделать проще.

При разборе вашего регулярного выражения видно, что всё вокруг `7[1-8]7` необязательно, все те шаблоны помечены квантификатором `?`, *один или ноль повторов*.

Таким образом, вы можете просто отбросить ненужные части и использовать

```
var kody = stroka.match(/7[1-8]7/)[0]
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ZaYMIy/1/).

Вы можете добавить точности этому выражению добавив проверку на отстутствие цифр слева и справа:

```
var kody = stroka.match(/(?:\D|^)(7[1-8]7)(?!\d)/)[1];
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ZaYMIy/2).

```js
var strs = ['787','Boeing 737','Boeing 757-200','Boeing 737-800 (winglets)','Boeing 777-300ER','Boeing 787-8','Boeing737-800(winglets)','Boeing737-800withwinglets','Boeing777-200/300','Boeing 747-8i','Boeing777-200/200ER'];
var rx = /(Boeing\s?)?(7[1-8]7)(-[0-9](00)?(\/[0-9]00)?)?i?((L|E)R)?(\s|with)?(\(?winglets\)?)?/;
for (var i=0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  console.log(strs[i], "=>", strs[i].match(/7[1-8]7/)[0]);
  console.log(strs[i], "=>", strs[i].match(/(?:\D|^)(7[1-8]7)(?!\d)/)[1]);
}
```